# What is wrong in my Bootstrap row and columns HTML code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works on desktop, but when I view this on small screen mobile device with size 240x320 I am not able to select and enter data into the text input field. But if I remove content(i.e. the '+' button in this case) from the last column of the row then the text input field is accessible.

I tested this on Android device with stock browser and Opera mini.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-sm-2` in your following code is the problem.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
</div>
```

Replace `col-sm-2` with `col-xs-2` to fix this.

**Why is this happening?**

Bootstrap in mobile first framework. Style for Mobile devices are defined with `col-xs-*` classes. `col-sm-*` styles will be applied on screens `>=768px`.

As all Boostrap's columns are styled with `float: left`. On small screens `col-xs-12` will create layout issue and following element i.e `col-sm-2` overlaps all previous elements. You can observe this issue in desktop too by reducing the size of your screen and checking with browser's inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by using the non-stacking columns (keeping everything on the same row)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***OR..***

Use a input group in a single column..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**working demo**](http://www.bootply.com/GjC5AlyDh4)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```